# Create PHP P2P game client tracker

Tags: php, c++, networking, p2p

At the moment I'm looking into creating a networked game using P2P. The game is not that high paced and I don't have access to a dedicated server, so P2P seems like a good choice to me. I do have access to a online domain. Programming is done in C++.

Oblivious to the perils of Game Networking I thought P2P did not need ANY sort of centralized server communication. Then I thought 'but how on earth can I find other game users hosting a game without knowing their IP?'. My thought now is that I need some kind of central 'hub' to which the game can connect to get a list of available peer hosts with their IP and port. It will then connect to that host and send data using UDP (I know it's connectionless, but it seems ENet has some tricks for that). If my idea is completely absurd, then let me know.

I had the idea to make a very simple PHP client-IP-switch-thingy on my online domain. The game won't attract more then 2 to 3 people because it's just for my personal learning goals so the load on that domain won't be too much of an issue, I think. Problem is that I can't really find any usable information on making anything of the sort using PHP. I tried to look through the 'similar questions' bit of SO, but I still can't find a lot of info.

**My question to you is: how can I create a PHP game client/host tracker, if possible at all? Do you know any good websites or articles on this?**

On a side note, I'm looking to use a combination of ENet and SFML, ENet for a reliable UDP packet and SFML for the packet builder. Is that a viable choice?

Comment: Is this game intended to work on LAN only or also/exclusively on internet ?

Comment: The absolute minimum would be LAN, but I would really like it to work via the internet as well. I don't care if a user had to manually open a port, I just want it to be possible.

Comment: All right. So, yes you will need a bare minimal centralized server to do this. Multicasting/broadcasting would have been an option in case of a LAN exclusive game.

Comment: At least I'm on the right track then. I suspect that I can't find any usable information because I got my terminology wrong. Does some kind of P2P Client tracker have a special name?

Comment: I answered your initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, several choices are acceptable for what you want to do.

Using P2P connections is tricky but can be powerfull, especially in low-latency fields such as VOIP and multiplayer online games.

I think you will need to expose a server that will handle the informations and the states  related to the connected players. I would recommend using `C++` for this part and [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/) for networking, as you will find plenty of well explained examples using those two, also you might find them *very* robust and scalable. But this is in the end, definitely up to you.

This component would have the role of accepting incoming connections from gamers that would like to join or create a game. It will hold the list of games and users currently connected and make them available to new incoming players.

Pretty simple, isn't it ? Now comes the choice you have to make about the gaming architecture. Choices here are using a `P2P` connection between players, or using your server as a proxy between each player.

**The server as a proxy**

The server holding informations about each game and players can be used to forward connections between the players. This is rather inneficient in terms of scalability and performance because you are creating a single point of failure which is your server, but as your requirements regarding this domain are low, it could be an option to you.

In this case, the server could accept a new connection (on another socket for instance) when a player wants to join a game and broadcast messages to all the other players so everyone in a game could receive an advert when another player joins, moves, shoots ...

**A Peer-to-peer connection**

That's a bit trickier. The server will always serve the purpose of knowing what players and games are currently existing, but instead of having the responsability to manage the connections between the users itself, it could simply tell a player that wants to join a game "Hey, you're about to join a new game, if you'd like to, please contact `10.20.30.40`". That would be the **public** IP address of the guy "hosting" the game.

You will then hit the first big difficulty. How are you going to communicate with this host if he's behind a router ? You'll need to implement NAT-traversal capabilities on the client side to allow an incoming player to get to the computer that hosts the game between his router.

Some techniques are used by VOIP apps to resolve this issue (think Skype) when they use [`UPnP's IGD (Internet Gateway Device)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal) to ask the router to open and redirect some port to the wanted computer. This is tricky, because it takes time and is not implemented on every router, so this could potentially lead to a complete failure. For the sake of this example, let's say we can easily overcome this issue and let's get to the next one.

When connected to the computed hosting the game, you can ask him what other players are also connected to the game and to advert other players that you are currently connected.
The idea here is to have every player in the match talking to each other about updates (again, that would be moves, shots, private messages or whatever), in order to keep every player in sync (and trust me they won't). You might also want to implement an ordering packet algorithm (preferably using UDP or ENet) in which you will define how adverts and messages will be broadcasted to the other players.

Take for example a match where 4 players are connected to. There is the host **Bob**, **Alice** his neighbour, **Tom** a guy living in New York and **Mike** another guy we need for the purpose of this example.

Alice connects to Bob's game first, she adverts Bob that she joined his game, on every updates Bob and Alice are exchanging informations about the current state of the match. Now Tom comes in and tells Bob he's a new player, Bob tells Tom that there is one other player connected and gives him her IP address (Alice's). Now Bob tells Alice that someone is connected and gives her his IP address. Imagine Bob dies, Bob will tell Alice he died because he was used to talk with her in the first place before Tom kicks in, and it is now Alice that needs to tell Tom that Bob just died.

You could simply have all the players broadcast to every players every advert but this would be a rather huge amount of data to process, and not so scalable given the number of players in a match. Using a *graph* for communication in a P2P environment could be far more efficient but would certainly take far more than just minutes to be explained.

I gave you my point of view about these techniques, use a classic client-server architecture if you want to stay simple, giving the load you'll need to handle, it will be more than acceptable.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Oh my, thanks a lot for this explanation :) It seems that P2P is a bit too difficult for me at the moment. This is the first time for me that I've done any game networking (to be frank, any type of real networking). This project should be some sort of 'intro' to the game networking realm. Maybe I'm better off with just a simple C++ server application running somewhere. What is your take on this? I will mark your answer as the accepted one and really, thanks! But let me still know your take on this ;)

Comment: I recommend using a server on a side that keeps in memory the current players and which knows who is playing with who, who's looking for a game and that responds accordingly to the need of each player. On the client side, using `SFML` is fine. You'll have to manage all the UI accordingly to the processed user/network events. I think writing this sort of program would be extremely benefic for your skills ;) I agree with what you'd like to do.